# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).stellar is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement the stellar plugin and far as I can see, I have included all the necessary js. However, in the dev tools console I keep getting the 'Uncaught TypeError: $(...).stellar is not a function'.

This is what I have in the head tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UFT-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>QE | Welcome</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stuff.css"/>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.stellar.js"></script>
 <script src="js/scrip.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.js"></script>
```

And this is is the scrip.js file that the error is referring to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(window).stellar();

});

$(document).ready(

     function() { 

     $("html").niceScroll({
         cursorcolor:"rgba(30,30,30,.5)",
         zindex:999,
         scrollspeed:100,
         mousescrollstep:50,
         cursorborder:"0px solid #fff",
     });

});
```

Please help me

Comment: On the Network tab of the Devtools, are you definitely fetching the `js/jquery.stellar.js` script correctly?

Comment: Yes the js/jquery.stellar.js status is ''Finished'

Comment: Is the Response data the contents of that file?

Comment: Yes as far as I can see the response data is the same as js/jquery.stellar.js

Comment: Can you reproduce it using [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co)?

Comment: I have found out that the problem was with js/vendor/jquery.js which was I forgotten that had placed that at the bottom of the index.html file. When I removed it, the stellar function worked. Not sure why that affects stellar.js though.

Comment: You should add that as an answer in case it helps other people solve a similar problem. I would imagine that it overwrote/reset the jQuery variables and configuration, so the plugin was not present by the time `document.ready` fired.

Comment: Thanks guys, appreciate your help.

Comment: It beacause duplicated jQuery load in porto. I got the same problem when try to install Porto theme to Magento2. See more detail at http://magento2developer.com/blog/javascript-error-with-magento-porto-theme.html to fix the bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found out that the problem was with js/vendor/jquery.js which was I forgotten that had placed that at the bottom of the index.html file. When I removed it, the stellar function worked. Not sure why that affects stellar.js though.

Comment: 1. Load jQuery. 2. Add stellar to jQuery. 3. Load a NEW jQuery that overwrites the old one (including anything added to it).

Answer (score 0):

1. Add javascript links to the Layout Page.
2. Remove script links from the inner page